# Hibernate select before updating

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to work out if there is a better way of doing the insert/update in the following scenario. I have two classes:

```
public class Person {

private int id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private Family family;
...
}


public class Family {

private int id;

private String name;
...
}
```

The primary key in both is Id (which I would like to keep that way for the purpose of this exercise). There is a many-to-one relationship between person and family, so many people can have the same family. My input method allows you to set any family value but I check before the insert to see if it exists:

```
public void savePerson(Person person) {
    System.out.println("Saving person");

    Family existingFamily = getFamily(person.getFamily().getName());
    if (existingFamily != null) {
        person.setFamily(existingFamily);
    }

    sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(person);
}
 ...

public Family getFamily(String name) {
    System.out.println("Getting family: " + name);
    Family family
      = (Family) sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Family where name = :name")
        .setParameter("name", name)
        .uniqueResult();
    return family;
}
```

My question is then can this be done automagically somehow through hibernate (which I am somewhat new to) or do I always need to check the database for an existing object beforehand (and update the Person)?

Cheers

Hojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for existing object by using `get()` method rather than writing `HQL query`

Example:

```
public boolean getFamily(int famId) {
Family family = (Family)sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().get(Family.class,famId);
     if(family!=null){
     return true;
     }
     else{
     return false;
     }
}
```

This is how I do in my projects.`get()` method returns Object if it present in DB else returns null.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I probably should have made it clearer but the input data just passes a "name" value for the family (which maybe existing or new) so I wouldn't have access to any Id/primary key value (why I wrote the HQL query). Looking around I think this might just be an odd unique case with my example where I need to select before update.